# Laravel retrieve the latest records by date and group them by label

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to retrieve the latest records by date, then by ID and group them by their label. So far, I can retrieve them correctly.
The issue is; I can't get the ID as it's a `group by` and it could potentially have more than 1 in the result.

##### The table

| id | label | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | quarterly | 2011-06-30 |
| 13 | quarterly | 2010-01-01 |
| 14 | annual | 2011-06-30 |
| 15 | annual | 2011-06-30 |
| 16 | monthly | 2012-06-30 |
| 17 | monthly | 2011-06-30 |

##### Expected result

| id | label | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | quarterly | 2011-06-30 |
| 15 | annual | 2011-06-30 |
| 16 | monthly | 2012-06-30 |

##### What I have tried

```php
$premiums = Premium::selectRaw('label, max(end_date) as end_date')
            ->groupBy('label')
            ->get();
```

Notes:

- I have tried to add `id` to the `selectRaw` but it returns the error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'premiums.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select label, max(end_date) as end_date, id from `premiums` group by `label`)

- I have also tried to add`max(id) as id` to the `selectRaw` but it returns me a wrong result
  (the ID does not match the corresponding date/label in the DB)

Comment: @Strawberry I would assume adding `max(id) as id` to the `selectRaw` would have gave me this. Since `group by label` doesn't allow you to have multiple ID, having the last one suits me as last priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In raw sql, perhaps you're after something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,label VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,end_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(12,'quarterly','2011-06-30'),
(13,'quarterly','2010-01-01'),
(14,'annual'   ,'2011-06-30'),
(15,'annual'   ,'2011-06-30'),
(16,'monthly'  ,'2012-06-30'),
(17,'monthly'  ,'2011-06-30');

SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT MAX(a.id) id
         FROM my_table a
         JOIN
            ( SELECT label
                   , MAX(end_date) end_date
                FROM my_table
               GROUP
                  BY label
            ) b
           ON b.label = a.label
          AND b.end_date = a.end_date
        GROUP
           BY a.label
     ) y
    ON y.id = x.id;
    
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | label     | end_date   |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 15 | annual    | 2011-06-30 |
| 16 | monthly   | 2012-06-30 |
| 12 | quarterly | 2011-06-30 |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Top notch! It works like a charm! Using `DB::select( your_query )` Thanks! :)